# How do I reset a lightning file input after submission?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, aura

How do I reset a lightning file input after it has been submitted?

Here is my input on the component:

```
<input type="file" class="file" aura:id="file" />
```

After the user submits the file it still has the old file selected and I want to clear it out after submission.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is more related to HTML than Lightning, how about this?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703228/how-to-clear-file-input-with-javascript

I saw some solutions that do not require you to replace the element which would be harmful here in lightning.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, that got me in the right direction. I was able to clear it using this where file is the aura:id

```
component.find("file").getElement().value='';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need create a String Aura Attribute and provide a value attribute in the Input tag, for eg.

```
<aura:attribute name="fileValue" type="String"  default="" />
<input type="file" class="file" aura:id="file" value="{!v.fileValue}" />
```

And When you want to reset the file, use the following command in JS:

```
component.find("file").set("v.value", "");
```